# ActiveMQ async statistics receiving

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

I am facing a pretty common error, but still haven't found a solution for it. I am using async message sending:

```
    Queue adminQueue=session.createQueue("admin_queue");
    MessageConsumer mc=session.createConsumer(adminQueue);              
    mc.setMessageListener(new AdminListener(emfMaster,ps));
    connection.start();

    this.statisticProvider = new AdminStats(adminQueue, mc, session);
```

And I need to receive statstics for it, using a Stat Plugin for ActiveMQ, which is stuffed into my AdminStats class(it starts a new thread for receiving stats), but still it tells, that I can use only sync message sending, not specifying the MessageListener.

```
[javax.jms.IllegalStateException: Cannot synchronously receive a message when a MessageListener is set]
```

I have no right to change the way messages are sent. Is there any way to get the stats in async way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get stats using JMX. Or with advisory messages. Some links from here: http://activemq.apache.org/how-can-i-monitor-activemq.html

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will try that. Also I've found a pretty weird decision: some people advice just to nullify the Listener inside the AdminStats class' message consumer, by not touching the actual consumer's listener. Thank you.