# ActiveMQ Getting Enqueue/Dequeue Count

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

In DEBUG mode, there is an ActiveMQ log as

```
09:44:10,666 [ActiveMQ Task-1] DEBUG  org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Queue:1687 - queue.demo toPageIn: 0, Inflight: 0, pagedInMessages.size 3, enqueueCount: 10, dequeueCount: 7
```

Is it possible that I can get same data inside of my Java code to get enqueueCount and dequeueCount?

Thanks.

ps. I've tried StatisticsPlugin but I guess I cannot use it because of async mode as mentioned in this question [ActiveMQ async statistics receving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12937705/activemq-async-statistics-receving)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course you can.
ActiveMQ exposes a lot of features and data through JMX.

Look at [the ActiveMQ JMX docs](http://activemq.apache.org/jmx.html) page. To get a feeling for the interface, use "jconsole" to browse through the MBeans and see what methods and attributs you might need (the previous link pretty much nails your question with a screenshot).

JMX is easily accessible via java, so just start coding. [Some starting points.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/)

Comment: Thanks @Petter . I could see my stats on jConsole GUI after I completed all steps in that JMX docs. Also I noticed that all stats comes from `QueueView` class of ActiveMQ. So I wrote a function to create `QueueView` object in my code. It is something like this if anyone interests:  http://rextester.com/JVK98556

Comment: I have 2 questions:

1) What class did you put the QueueView code in?  I'm trying to figure out how to leverage this for a project in which I have similar needs to your question. 

2) How and where do I leverage that method? A listener? Somewhere else?

I'm trying to write a REST endpoint where I can return the dequeue count for some ActiveMQ queues, but cannot for the life of me figure out how to get the actual queue information.