# How can I get the enqueue and dequeue count for an ActiveMQ queue WITHIN my Java Spring app?

Tags: java, spring, queue, activemq-classic

I have been scouring the internet for documentation on this and it's unbelievable how difficult it is to find. My goal is to create a REST endpoint where I can return queue details such as enqueue, dequeue, etc. counts for a custom dashboard I am making.

I keep seeing documentation such as [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/), [this](https://activemq.apache.org/jmx), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26038994/activemq-getting-enqueue-dequeue-count), but I can't seem to figure out how to get these details in my actual program. I have gotten about as far as using the JMX GUI, but that really is not the direction I need to be going. Can anyone help me figure out how to get simple connection to a broker that will return these details? I really have tried to research this, but I have not been able to figure out a way to incorporate this information to my application in any meaningful away.

Answer (score 0):

The way to monitor the broker is via the broker [JMX](https://activemq.apache.org/jmx) endpionts and the management beans it exposes.  Other means would be through the Jolokia REST API that exposes those same MBeans.  One article showing how to use the Jolokia bits is [here](https://www.jakubkorab.net/2013/11/monitoring-activemq-via-http.html).

A brief example of using JMX with ActiveMQ is below.

```
// connection
String url = "service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi";
JMXConnector connector = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(new JMXServiceURL(url));
MBeanServerConnection connection = connector.getMBeanServerConnection();
// get queue size
ObjectName nameConsumers = new ObjectName("org.apache.activemq:type=Broker,brokerName=localhost,destinationType=Queue,destinationName=myqueue");
DestinationViewMBean mbView = MBeanServerInvocationHandler.newProxyInstance(connection, nameConsumers, DestinationViewMBean.class, true);
long queueSize = mbView.getQueueSize();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Tim. I have read the JMX document that you posted, but I am struggling with how to implement that into my Java application. None of that seems to include code examples that I can use to understand how to leverage this for my own purposes. That seems to be the answer that I keep circling back to, but it seems that my understanding isn't advanced enough to be able to implement that based on that documentation alone. Could you provide any extra tips for structuring my application to incorporate this?

Comment: Everything I see seems to be pointing to how to interface with JConsole or a similar GUI through arbitrary MBean examples and nothing related to actual code implementation of queue info.